# Can Somebody Explain this Function?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

```
function doesOwnSet(player, type) {
// we'll use "chaining" here, so every next method will be called upon
// what previous method have returned

// `return` statement will return the result of the very last method

// first, lets take an array of `position` object keys
// which are "position1", "position2" and so on
return Object.keys(positions)

    // then, create an array of positions object
    // this will return Array
    .map(function (key) {
        return positions[key];
    })

    // then, pick up only positions with specified type (aka set)
    // this will return Array
    .filter(function (pos) {
        return pos.type === type;
    })

    // finally, check if specified player owns every position of the set
    // this will return Boolean
    .every(function (pos) {
        return pos.owner === player;
    });
}
```

I don't understand where the words "key" and "pos" come from. Are these the names of the functions? I really don't get it despite the comments. It was an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848475/monopoly-check-if-player-owns-a-set/). The code works, but I just don't understand what it does.

Comment: Those are function parameters…

Comment: Really basic question.

Comment: I don't understand the part where it filters. It says .filter(function (pos) { what does that mean?

Comment: @EltonFrederik  I'm pretty sure those are jQuery functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an Array of the "own" keys of the object.

The `.map()`, `.filter()` and `.every()` iterate the array, passing each value to the callback one at a time, so the `key` in `.map()` is the object key for the current iteration.

Whatever `.map()` callback returns gets added as a member of a new Array, which is returned, so `.filter()` and `.every()` operate on the new Array values.

The `.filter()` will create an Array of the values where the callback returned `true` (or any truthy value).

The `.every()` will return `true` if its callback returns a truthy value for every iteration, otherwise it returns `false`.

Put calls to `console.log()` inside the callbacks to see what the values hold.

```
function doesOwnSet(player, type) {
// we'll use "chaining" here, so every next method will be called upon
// what previous method have returned

// `return` statement will return the result of the very last method

// first, lets take an array of `position` object keys
// which are "position1", "position2" and so on
return Object.keys(positions)

    // then, create an array of positions object
    // this will return Array
    .map(function (key) {
        console.log(key);
        return positions[key];
    })

    // then, pick up only positions with specified type (aka set)
    // this will return Array
    .filter(function (pos) {
        console.log(pos);
        return pos.type === type;
    })

    // finally, check if specified player owns every position of the set
    // this will return Boolean
    .every(function (pos) {
        console.log(pos);
        return pos.owner === player;
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing the use of console.log to show what this is actually doing. I also think it's worth mentioning anonymous functions/delegates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work. In this case, _key_ and _pos_ are just parameters of the delegate.

Comment: I just did it. It basically mirrors the values of my "positions" object.

Comment: @EltonFrederik: The `key` parameter will give the  keys, not the values. In other words, if `positions` is `{foo: "bar", baz: "buz"}`, you'll get `foo` and `baz`. To get the values you'd use `positions[key]`, which will be the same as `positions["foo"]` and `positions["baz"]`

Comment: ...the values are then mapped to a new Array because `.map()` returns `positions[key]`, so `.filter()` and `every()` will operate on the values, so `pos` would be `"bar"` and `"buz"`.

Comment: So pos is just a name, it could have been position or p etc ?

Comment: @EltonFrederik: Yes it's a function parameter, which is a name that references whatever was passed to the function.